# Cropping and extract only the object in an image using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I have to extract an object from an image. So I have used below code found in one of the websites to extract the object. But the output is not proper. Below is the sample input and output image.

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {


Mat img0 = imread("/home/user/Pictures/check2.JPG", 1);

Mat img1;
cvtColor(img0, img1, CV_RGB2GRAY);

// apply your filter
Canny(img1, img1, 100, 200);

// find the contours
vector< vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(img1, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

// you could also reuse img1 here
Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img1.rows, img1.cols, CV_8UC1);

// CV_FILLED fills the connected components found
drawContours(mask, contours, -1, Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

// let's create a new image now
Mat crop(img0.rows, img0.cols, CV_8UC3);

// set background to black
crop.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0));

// and copy 
img0.copyTo(crop, mask);
// normalize so imwrite(...)/imshow(...) shows the mask correctly!
normalize(mask.clone(), mask, 0.0, 255.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);

// show the images
imshow("cropped", crop);

imwrite("/home/user/Pictures/check1_cropped.JPG", crop);

waitKey();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Input_Image]
[image: Output_Image]

The expected output is to get the **player** only in black background ( or any other color specified), but here the output is getting overlapped with black. I want the cropped player on top of black background. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I guess Grabcut would be more apt for this problem than Canny: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html

Comment: @ZdaR I have used grabcut but had some issues such as the final output image was blueish

Comment: It may be blueish due to some RGB to BGR conversion